# Modifying ACL in Parse Server

Tags: acl, parse-server

I'm trying to modify the ACL of an object without creating another one. I don't want the current ACL to be deleted or overwritten. Whenever I use `object.setACL()` it overwrites the current ACL.

Is there a way to save the modified the ACL without overwriting it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the existing ACL object by calling `object.getACL()`. From there you can edit/add more roles or users without overwriting the existing ones.

Once you've modified the existing ACL, you can then `object.setACL(modifiedAcl)` to save the modifications.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot

Comment: It's object.getACL not acl damn! I wasted 20 minutes on this. Correct it